# Background 100%

Tags: html, css, background

I'm building a website and I'm running into one problem.
The image of the top of the site is not getting 100% in size, in computers everything is ok but on the cell phone it gets this bar blank.
I tried everything, researched forums, tried everything and could not find a solution.

This layout is not responsive, it is only adaptable for mobile screens.
Below is a screenshot of the site and part of the code.

If someone want to visit the website, follow the link:
http://www.cr6arquitetura.com.br/

[IMAGE MOBILE WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai8lH.jpg)

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5.0em;
  color: #efc500;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 25px;
}

#bgmain {
  background: url(img/main.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-color: #efc500;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#barra {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80%);
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #efc500;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #efc500;
}

#textomiddle {
  width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#botao {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80%);
}

#botao:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100%);
}

a.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #efc500;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 17px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="bgmain">
  <!-- THIS IS THE MAIN DIV FOR THE BACKGROUND IMAGE-->
  <!-- -->
  <div id="barra">
    <!-- THIS IS THE WHITE BAR ON TOP OF WEBSITE-->
    <div id="logo">
      <!--THIS IS THE LOGO ON TOP LEFT -->
      <img class="logo" src="img/cr6logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <!-- DIV LOGO END-->
    <nav id="menu">
      <!-- THIS IS THE MENU -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NOSSOS TRABALHOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- MENU END-->
  </div>
  <!-- BARRA END -->
  <div id="textomiddle">
    <!-- This is the DIV that stays in the dima of the banner -->
    <center>
      <h1>SOLUÇÃO COMPLETA EM ARQUITETURA</h1>
    </center>
    <div id="botao">
      <center><a class="link" href="contato.html">FAÇA UM ORÇAMENTO</a></center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END DIV TEXTOMIDDLE -->
</div>
<!-- END DIV BGMAIN-->
```

Comment: Do you have a live url?

Comment: Please check the validity of your HTML here: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
After that organize and indent your code.

Comment: @PatrickMacCann yes i have, follow it: http://www.cr6arquitetura.com.br/

Comment: @PeterLeger the code is already verfied and now I identified the code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
#bgmain {width:1080px;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 519px) {
#bgmain {width:100%;}
}
```

Comment: I did this and the whole website turn to the left.

Comment: I edited my response, see if that works @DouglasMion

Comment: Thanks again, but i did this and the whole website turn to the left again. I want to leave the computer version OK first, then repair the phone version.
At the moment, without this command "POSITION: ABSOLUTE" the PC version is OK

Comment: Can u check the website on desktop and your mobile phone? www.cr6arquitetura.com.br

Comment: @DouglasMion It seems like the 1080px width on some of your divs is making the 100% width on other divs, push the content to the left and create that gap. If you look at my updated answer this should solve your top image problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your support.. i'll do the thing you told and still the same problem :\